# Circular dot on matplotlib barh graph

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'y':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']\
                       ,'x':[10,9,9,8,7,6,10,6,7]})
df.sort_values(by='x',inplace=True,ascending = True)

plt.barh(bottom=list(range(1,10)), width=df.x, height = 0.15, align='center',color = 'blue')
plt.xlim([0,11])
plt.yticks(list(range(1,10)),skills.y)
plt.show()
```

This code gives me a horizontal bar graph. 
I want to add a circular dot at the edge of each bars. 
Can someone please help me with that.
[Tableau graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55AlS.jpg)
I did this in tableau, I want to replicate the same in python.
Also, please let me know if there a better way of coding the same.

I am using Anaconda Python 3.5, Matplotlib library, Windows 10, Idlex IDE

Answer (score 4):

You could just add a scatterplot on top of your bars, using matplotlib [`scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) function.

Also, note that you could use the [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) function to generate your x values, instead of your current `list(range(1,10))`.

See example below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],
                   'x':[10,9,9,8,7,6,10,6,7]})

df.sort_values(by='x',inplace=True,ascending = True)

plt.barh(bottom=np.arange(len(df)), width=df.x, height = 0.15, align='center',color = 'blue')
plt.scatter(df.x.values, y=np.arange(df.shape[0]), color='b', s=40)
plt.xlim([0,11])
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(df)),df.y)
plt.show()
```

[image: img]